# Inject inline script in cordova wkwebview IOS

Tags: cordova, inject

Alright, so i've seen all the threads but can't seem to get it to work.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; media-src *; img-src *">
```

If i directly add:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        alert('Hello world');
</script>
```

this works.

..but.. if i inject it from localStorage it crashes the app. I can inject html and css perfectly fine though.

I have these NPMs installed:

```
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine" spec="git+https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine.git#1.0.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr" spec="^1.0.0" />
```

Comment: Show us how you inject from localStoage

Answer (score 0):

I use this small function to load it. Which works with UIwebview

```
Nate.createScript = function(input){
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]
  var el = document.createElement('script')
  el.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript')
  el.innerText = input
  head.appendChild(el)
}
```

And localstorage looks something like:

```
localStorage.js = "alert('hello world')";
Nate.createScript(localStorage.js)
```

Comment: Actually, that worked -.- 
Problem apparently resides when loading the whole js which is webpack generated code. 

It throws this error in xcode:
WebPageProxy.DecidePolicyForNavigationAction

It complains in safari console with some fonts not found before crashing